# Is it possible to update a THREE.Texture with a gl.Texture_2D bound to a native framebuffer?

Tags: three.js, framebuffer

The idea:
Create a renderTexture with a native WebGL framebuffer to be able to use "WEBGL_draw_buffers" and output more than one attachment (COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_WEBGL, COLOR_ATTACHMENT1_WEBGL, COLOR_ATTACHMENT2_WEBGL, ...)

```
glFragData[0] = ...
glFragData[1] = ...
glFragData[2] = ...
glFragData[3] = ...
```

Then, try to update some THREE.DataTextures with these attached native WebGL texture2D bound to the framebuffer.

All is going fine with my native framebuffer with WEBGL_draw_buffers extension... but I don't find a way to update the threejs texture. I tried many things by looking how Threejs handles WebGLRenderTarget ... but nothing is working... no way to update a THREE.Texture with a native WebGL Texture2D.

I don't want to use WebGLRenderTarget because there is only one COLOR_ATTACHMENT and it does not support "WEBGL_draw_buffers" extension.
Maybe it will be nice to handle this in the future ;)

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Here is what I mean in terms of code:

```
var scene;
var camera;
var renderer;
var debugMaterial;
var posTextureOut;

function init()
{
    // create a data texture + generate a gl.Texture2D for it

    posTextureOut = new THREE.DataTexture(posTextureData, rttSize, rttSize, THREE.RGBAFormat, THREE.FloatType);
    posTextureOut.__webglTexture = gl.createTexture();
    posTextureOut.__webglInit = true;
    posTextureOut.needsUpdate = true;

    // create a framebuffer and bind posTextureOut.__webglTexture to it

    rttFramebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
    renderFrameBuffer = gl.createRenderbuffer();

        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, posTextureOut.__webglTexture);
        //gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, rttSize, rttSize, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null);
        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, rttFramebuffer);
        gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, ext.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_WEBGL, gl.TEXTURE_2D, posTextureOut.__webglTexture, 0);
        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);


        // Bind RenderBuffer to FrameBuffer Depth and Stencil attachment

        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, rttFramebuffer);
        gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, renderFrameBuffer);
        gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_STENCIL, rttSize, rttSize );
        gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, renderFrameBuffer );
        gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, null);
        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);



    // create material with classic vert/frag shaders + posTextureOut as mainTexture

    debugMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms:
        {
            texture: { type: "t", value: posTextureOut }
        },
        vertexShader: shaderLoader.GetData("simulVert"),
        fragmentShader:  shaderLoader.GetData("simulFrag"),  
        transparent: true,
        needsUpdate: true
   });

   var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 128, 128, 8, 8 );
   plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, debugMaterial );

   scene.add( plane );
}

function render()
{
   gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, rttFramebuffer);

   // Draw some stuff width gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements

   gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);


   // ... find a way to update posTextureOut width the native texture2D from the framebuffer


   renderer.resetGLState();  // errors in renderer if this is not called (??)

   renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

If i do this, I get it working partially :

```
function render()
{
   gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, rttFramebuffer);

   // Draw some stuff width gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements

   gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);


   renderer.resetGLState(); 


   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, posTextureOut.__webglTexture);

   renderer.render(scene, camera);

   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}
```

But it doesn't really fit with the ThreeJS renderer pipeline and I have no control on which activeTexture is used, no matter what gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0) gl.TEXTURE1, gl.TEXTURE2 is passed before the binding.

I really would like to get my posTextureOut (THREE.DataTexture) updated from my mesh material with the content of a custom framebuffer.

It sounds like THREE.Textures does not take in account any change onto its __webglTexture.

Thanks

Q.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I found why I cannot update a THREE.Texture with texture2D reference.

To setup a THREE.Texture with a gl.createTexture(), I found this by googling:

```
posTextureOut = new THREE.DataTexture(posTextureData, rttSize, rttSize, THREE.RGBAFormat, THREE.FloatType);
posTextureOut.__webglTexture = gl.createTexture();
posTextureOut.__webglInit = true;
posTextureOut.needsUpdate = true;
```

Then, if you want to bind this texture to a native framebuffer and do some native webgl stuff on it, you can do it like that:

```
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, rttFramebuffer);
...
ext.drawBuffersWEBGL([ext.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_WEBGL, ext.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1_WEBGL]);

gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, posTextureOut.__webglTexture);
...
...
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
```

The problem what to get the THREE.Texture updated with this modified posTextureOut.__webglTexture

Using needsUpdate = true does not helped me and cause a lot a errors due to bad texture binding to the THREE.WebGLRenderer.

By looking in the source code, I found the problem.
In THREE.WebGLRenderer, the this.setTexture method is looking like this:

```
this.setTexture = function ( texture, slot ) {

    var textureProperties = properties.get( texture );

    if ( texture.version > 0 && textureProperties.__version !== texture.version ) {

        var image = texture.image;

        if ( image === undefined ) {

            console.warn( 'THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture marked for update but image is undefined', texture );
            return;

        }

        if ( image.complete === false ) {

            console.warn( 'THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture marked for update but image is incomplete', texture );
            return;

        }

        uploadTexture( textureProperties, texture, slot );

        return;
    }

    state.activeTexture( _gl.TEXTURE0 + slot );
    state.bindTexture( _gl.TEXTURE_2D, textureProperties.__webglTexture );

};
```

And the this.uploadTexture method is doing this :

```
function uploadTexture( textureProperties, texture, slot ) {

    if ( textureProperties.__webglInit === undefined ) {

        textureProperties.__webglInit = true;

        texture.addEventListener( 'dispose', onTextureDispose );

        textureProperties.__webglTexture = _gl.createTexture();

        _infoMemory.textures ++;

    }
```

At this point, textureProperties.__webglInit is always undefined, even if it's forced before. Same fore textureProperties.__webglTexture... always undefined.

I fixed this by force this.setTexture to look at the texture and see if there is any change on this proporties... otherwise, the renderer does not take it in account.

Here are the 2 lines I added:

```
this.setTexture = function ( texture, slot ) {

    var textureProperties = properties.get( texture );

    if (texture.__webglInit != undefined) textureProperties.__webglInit = texture.__webglInit;
    if (texture.__webglTexture != undefined) textureProperties.__webglTexture = texture.__webglTexture;

    if ( texture.version > 0 && textureProperties.__version !== texture.version ) {

        var image = texture.image;

        ....
```

All is working fine now... and I can handle a THREE.Texture __webglTexture in native WebGL :)